# Sign up causing redirect loop in Devise for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, registration

Using Rails 3.2.9 and Devise 2.1.2. When users go to `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up` (same for production with `localhost:3000` replaced with the URL), they sign up. When submitting they get redirected to `/users/sign_up` repeatedly. Chrome reports:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up has resulted in too many redirects.
```

The logs say that the user was created and the users table was also updated for signing in (and in fact the user was created and logged in on the website if we then go to another URL):

```
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "em
ail", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "last_name", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "middle_name", "p
latform_id", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "update
d_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 17 Nov 201
2 08:39:33 PST -08:00], ["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["email", "test@ucode.com"],
 ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$NvmaFtw/JjILrkmkDNOi7ePj29qI3LRB2zTLAxsw6GRAW7PZekGme"], ["first_name", "Test"
], ["last_name", ""], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["middle_name", ""], ["platform_id",
 1], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["sign_in_c
ount", 0], ["updated_at", Sat, 17 Nov 2012 08:39:33 PST -08:00], ["username", "test"]]
  ←[1m←[36m (4.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mcommit transaction←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  begin transaction
  ←[1m←[36m (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mUPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2012-11-17 16:39:33.934552', "current_sig
n_in_at" = '2012-11-17 16:39:33.934552', "last_sign_in_ip" = '127.0.0.1', "current_sign_in_ip" = '127.0.0.1',
"sign_in_count" = 1, "updated_at" = '2012-11-17 16:39:33.953553' WHERE "users"."id" = 3←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (4.0ms)←[0m  commit transaction
```

Then the logs report the redirect loop:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
Completed 302 Found in 178ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-17 08:39:33 -0800
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1←[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-17 08:39:34 -0800
```

This surprisingly seems to be the default behavior as another new project experiences the exact same behavior. Am I not supposed to direct people to /users/sign_up to sign up?

Output of `rake routes` related to users:

```
     new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                            devise/sessions#new
         user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                            devise/sessions#create
 destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                           devise/sessions#destroy
        user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                           devise/passwords#create
    new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                       devise/passwords#new
   edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                      devise/passwords#edit
                      PUT    /users/password(.:format)                           devise/passwords#update
```

cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                             devise/registrations#cancel
        user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                    devise/registrations#create
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                            devise/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                               devise/registrations#edit
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                                    devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                                    devise/registrations#destroy

Comment: can you show your sign up view?

Comment: Can you post your Users Controller? You probably have a before filter to authenticate the user in your users controller.

Comment: sign up view was not modified from Devise's generated view. Users controller doesn't exist. Devise handles the /users/* requests.

Comment: Do you have a custom sessions controller?

Comment: Can you post the output of `rake routes` related to `users`?

Comment: @stevanity - no sessions controller